# Database select and schema create on Controller Symfony2

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, controller, doctrine

I'm trying to create a new database and load the schema from the Controller.

I created the database on the fly, but don't know how I can select that new database to load the schema.

This is my code:

## parameters.yml

```
parameters:

    # Admin database
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: '3306'
    database_name: app_db
    database_user: root
    database_password: XXX

    # A Center database
    database_driver2: pdo_mysql
    database_host2: localhost
    database_port2: '3306'
    database_name2: center_1
    database_user2: root
    database_password2: XXX
```

## config.yml

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:

            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8

            center:
                driver:   %database_driver2%
                host:     %database_host2%
                port:     %database_port2%
                dbname:   %database_name2%
                user:     %database_user2%
                password: %database_password2%
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        #auto_mapping: true

        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:

            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    BackendBundle: ~
                    CenterBundle: ~
            center:
                connection: center
                mappings:
                    UsuarioBundle: ~
```

In the controller when i add a new center i create the database on the fly, center_1, center_2...

```
###################
# CREATE DATABASE #
###################

$connectionFactory = $this->container->get('doctrine.dbal.connection_factory');

$connection = $connectionFactory->createConnection(array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => XXX,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'dbname' => 'center_'.$center->getId(),
));

$params = $connection->getParams();
$name = isset($params['path']) ? $params['path'] : $params['dbname'];

unset($params['dbname']);

$tmpConnection = DriverManager::getConnection($params);

// Only quote if we don't have a path
if (!isset($params['path'])) {
    $name = $tmpConnection->getDatabasePlatform()->quoteSingleIdentifier($name);
}

$error = false;

try {
    $tmpConnection->getSchemaManager()->createDatabase($name);
    echo sprintf('<info>Created database for connection named <comment>%s</comment></info>', $name);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo sprintf('<error>Could not create database for connection named <comment>%s</comment></error>', $name);
    echo sprintf('<error>%s</error>', $e->getMessage());
    $error = true;
}

$tmpConnection->close();
```

My question is, how i could select that database and load the schema.

Is posible change on the fly the parameters.yml for a Center database, and then execute de command:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:create --em=center
```

If is not posible, another idea of ​​how to do it?

*************** EDIT 14/01/13

I add an example that i like, maybe I have not explained well.

When i add a new center, the above code create a new center, and a new database for this center, for example the database call "center_13"

Now if i like create the database schema i need go to parameters.yml and create a new parameters for this database

## parameters.yml

```
parameters:

    ....

    # A Center database
    database_name_13: center_13
```

also i need create a new connection in config.yml

## config.yml

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:

            default:
                ...

            center_13:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name_13%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        #auto_mapping: true

        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:

            default:

                ...

            center_13:
                connection: center_13
                mappings:
                    UsuarioBundle: ~
```

now if i run the command

```
app/console doctrine:schema:create --em=center_13
```

it configure the database "center_13" with the UsuarioBundle entities.

I'd like know how to do this process in de create center action of my controller

Answer (score 1):

The commands

> app/Console doctrine:schema:create

or

> app/console doctrine:schema:update

will configure your database as defined in your model configuration, but not from a controller.

You could [create a custom symfony command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html) and associate it to your *createDatabaseController* but I would make sure it's worth the effort first.

Comment: yes, i understand you.. maybe I have not explained well, i edit the question and added a example. Thanks!

Comment: Is it only for testing purpose or do you want this behaviour in production ?